# Using PHP in Joomla 2.5, is there a decent way to create groups without going through the menu or SQL?

Tags: php

I have been working on a custom component but now hit on an issue where I need to set up groups for ACL reasons. However, I cannot seem to find a valid method - I've crashed things so far. The group setup happens in the installation script, or at least should. A previous answer suggested this:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath( JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . 
                '/components/com_users/models/', 'UsersModel' );
$groupModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'Group', 'UsersModel' );


$groupData = array(
    'title' => "NHCommision",
    'parent_id' => 5,
    'id' => 9
);

$groupModel->save( $groupData );
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working in the final version of 2.5. Based on the "Legacy" add it might be ment for 3.0 - is there a 2.5 equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

This code is actually for Joomla 3.x, and I skipped v2.5, so can't be sure that it will work, but if not, perhaps it will give you a starting point to find the v2.5 equivalent:

```
 $basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_users';
require_once $basePath.'/models/group.php';
require_once $basePath.'/models/level.php';

$model = new UsersModelGroup(array('table_path' => $basePath.'/tables'));
$data = array('id'=>0, 'parent_id' => '2','title'=>'MyUserGroup');
if(!$model->save($data)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: No luck had so far, I'm still searching for some kind of answer on this.